# How to get all Wikipedia page links with their pageIDs?

Tags: wikipedia-api

Starting a request like that:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Title&prop=links&pllimit=500
```

provides me a list of links (that the page contains) where every link consists of the title and the ns (namespace)

Is there a way to also get the PageID together with title & ns? (the less work it is for the sever the better of course)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) parameter. Here is an example for [Cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra) Wikipedia page.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&titles=Cobra&prop=info&gpllimit=500
```